# How to create a chat program using php and mysqli for chatting

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, authentication, registration

I need to know that how i can create a chat program using php and mysqli
for chatting
Till now I created a Login & Registration form for my website you can visit and see the design and work of my website http://programmingvivek.twomini.com/
So please help me I am new in PHP
And How to refresh messages using ajax

Comment: Do some research on web sockets!

Comment: I searched many paces but didn't find

Comment: http://socketo.me/

Comment: I found [this](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajax-web-chat-php-mysql/), a bit old but working. I hope it's inspire you!

Answer (score 2):

One way for doing message load asynchronously is using Javascript "jQuery" Library:

1) You can make request POST||GET request with jQuery to PHP File Like this:

```
$.post("path/to/phpfile.php",{"loadmessages":"*"},function(data){

     console.log(data); //Here will be loaded PHP file echo data;

  });
```

2) Then you must make PHP file like this

```
 if(isset($_POST['loadmessages'])){

    //get messages from mysql then echo them

           echo "response";

    }
```

3) then you can append that response to your chat pool with jQuery.